# Не работает ssh клиент для iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ssh

Попробовал установить *ssh term*. Но не могу подключиться к своему серверу - "unable to Connect with server". Хотя через putty и ssh клиенты для Андроид все работает.

Пароль, пользователя и ip я ввожу правильно.

Подскажите, проблема в клиенте, или в айфоне что-то дополнительно настроить надо?